# Why do I have a segfault somewhere else in my program when I free an allocated memory within a function?

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks, heap-memory

I'm having a tough time debugging some wierd memory issue. 
As you can see in the function below, This function just returns either zero or one. So I need to free allocated memory ('ps8linetmp').

```
ST_INT IsTypeMatch(ST_CHAR* ps8line)
{

    ST_CHAR* ps8substr;
    ST_CHAR* ps8type;
    ST_INT i = 0, s32daio = 0;
    ST_INT s32linenum;
    ST_CHAR* ps8linetmp;

    ps8linetmp = strdup(ps8line);
    ps8substr = strchr(ps8linetmp, ',');
    ps8substr = strchr(ps8substr, '=');
    ps8substr++;
    ps8type = strtok(ps8substr, ",");

    while(ps8substr != NULL)
    {
        if(i == 1)
            break;
        ps8substr = strtok(NULL, ",");
        i++;
    }
    s32daio = GetDigit(ps8substr);
    if(!strcmp(ps8type, "float"))
    {
        free(ps8linetmp);
        if(s32daio == 1 || s32daio == 2)
        {
            printf("Type of DI/DO can't be float\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    if(ps8linetmp != NULL)
        free(ps8linetmp);
    return 1;

}
```

I'm pretty sure I need to free 'ps8linetmp' since I've used strdup to allocated memory for it. The problem is I have a segfault somewhere else when I free the memory. The place where segfault occurs doesn't even seem to be related with the function. I don't understand why the segmentation fault doesn't occur when I don't free the memory and why the segfault doesn't occur within the function. 
This problem is beyond my reach, so any code guru's help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Note that you potentially have two `free`s there.

Comment: There is a code path that calls `free(ps8linetmp);` twice.

Comment: Use [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) and the [address sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer). Take the habit of clearing every pointer after having `free`d it

Comment: Having done that, a `NULL` pointer can be safely passed to `free` where it is ignored.

Comment: And of course, read about [undefined behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)